# Codename One - iOS Certificate Wizard can't login

Tags: codenameone, apple-id

Shortview:

1. Log in via *iOS Certificate Wizard*
2. Access alert - press **Allow**
3. "*Enter passcode on your device*"

When trying to log in via **iOS Certificate Wizard** I receive message like "*wrong username/password*" and alert on iPhone "*Someone accessing your Apple ID from New York* etc.".

There is two buttons - "**Allow**" and "**Disallow**", but when I press "**Allow**" **iPhone shows one-time password and asks me to enter it**. Where should I enter this or is there any bypass?

**P.S.**: Tried using application password (generated at *Apple ID* profile management page) but without any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Certificate Wizard doesn't support two factor authentication.  [This issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1995) is marked for version 3.7 (due in June).

In order to use the CertificateWizard, for now, you'll need to turn off 2-factor auth.  [This article](http://osxdaily.com/2016/08/17/disable-two-factor-authentication-apple-id/) describes how to do it.